# Ordinary Generating functions that occurs at most 3 times

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I need help finding the generating function for $R_n$, where $R_n$ is the number of partitions of $n$ in which each part occurs at most $3$ times...

I know that it is an infinite product and might look like this

$$R_n = (1 +x + x^2 + x^3)\cdot(1 + x^2 + x^4 + x^6)\cdot \ldots$$
which might simplify to..

$$R_n = \frac{1}{1-x^3}$$
but I'm not too sure.

Comment: what do you mean by "each par"?

Comment: OK, so the first term of your product will deal with the possibilities of having a part $1$ occurring $0,1,2$ or $3$ times. So the next term should deal with parts of size $2$. So it should be ...um, what's that $x^3$ doing there?

Comment: I meant to put $(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6)...$ but what I'm  asking for is if I have a general Idea of what I am doing. 
Unless you mean by this $(1+x + x^2)(1 + x^2 + x^4)...$

Comment: the "each part" is written in the book exercise like this, I do not know exactly what it means, which is why I am asking here and and have been looking online

Comment: The generating function is indeed $$(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6)(1+x^3+x^6+x^9)(1+x^4+x^8+x^{12})\cdots$$ but that is not equal to $R_n,$ it is equal to $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty R_nx^n.$$ And $\frac1{1-x^3}$ is not equal to $R_n$ nor to the generating function of $R_n,$ it is equal to the infinite geometric series $1+x^3+x^6+x^9+\cdots.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ordinary generating function for $R_n$ is
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty R_nx^n=(1+x+x^2+x^3)(1+x^2+x^4+x^6)(1+x^3+x^6+x^9)(1+x^4+x^8+x^{12})\cdot\cdots=\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+x^n+x^{2n}+x^{3n})=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1-x^{4n}}{1-x^n}.$$

Comment: Great! Thanks for the help, now if I were to solve for $R_1,R_2, ... R_6$ how would I go about doing that, would I do some partial fractions to create a formula in which I could plug in $n$ for the numbers 1 - 6?

Comment: If you just need the values of $R_n$ for $n\le6$ I think the easiest way is just to count them by hand. E.g., for $n=7$ the $15$ unrestricted partitions are $7=6+1=5+2=5+1+1=4+3=4+2+1=4+1+1+1=3+3+1=3+2+2=3+2+1+1=\underline{3+1+1+1+1}=2+2+2+1=2+2+1+1+1=\underline{2+1+1+1+1+1}=\underline{1+1+1+1+1+1+1}.$ Since we don't want any part repeated more than three times, we throw out the three (underlined) partitions where $1$ is repeated four or more times, so $R_7=12.$

Comment: Great! Thank you for being prompt and clear about my question. I appreciate it.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, then that must mean if $n=6$ then there are $11$ unrestricted partitions but if I remove the ones where I have more than three of each number, in this case, the $1$'s then I should have 9 total partitions?

Comment: That's correct.